# Google Cardboard setVRModeEnabled(false) not displaying anything

Tags: android, virtual-reality

I'm working on an app and am modifying the Treasure Hunt sample code.  I have a visual effect that isn't working correctly that I'd like to debug.  It is difficult to do in stereo mode.  It seems I could just call cardboardView.setVRModeEnabled(false); in onCreate() and it would not do the distortion correction and only render one eye.  That would be perfect.

However, all I see is black.

I reduced my onDrawEye() to simply:

```
glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

When setVRModeEnabled is true, my screen is red.  When it is false, all I see is black.  Any ideas?